# Inserting data into table using COPY causes constraint violation

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have an SQL file that contains the schema of the database (creating of tables and some functions to check the constraints). One of the functions has different actions to do for the first entered value and for the rest. What I mean is, that in the function I am firstly counting the number of elements in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    column1 INT,
    column2 INT CHECK(func())
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1()
    returns BOOLEAN
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$
         BEGIN
              SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var1 FROM table_name;
              RAISE NOTICE 'count: %', var1;
              IF var1 = 0 THEN 
                 ...
                 return true;
              ELSE 
                 ...
                 return true;
              END IF;
              return false;
         END;
    $$;
...
```

and if it is 0, then it does some checks for the first element, and else it does a bit different checks. Then to insert the data I am using COPY(in another SQL file):

```
COPY table_name(column1, column2) FROM stdin;
5 2 
8 7 
\.
```

but I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "table_name" violates check constraint "table_name_check"
```

for the second row. So, I have added RAISE NOTICE to print the count in my schema(as shown in the first block of code above):

```
RAISE NOTICE 'count: %', var1;
```

and for the first insert, it gives me count = 0, but for the second I also get count = 0. That is why the function treats the second insert as if it is first and it causes errors. What could be the reason for this problem? It looks like even if the first row has been inserted, there are still no rows on the table after the first insertion.

Comment: Presumably the COPY INTO statement doesn't commit until the end so until that point the count will always be zero? Try inserting one row first and if that works, try then inserting multiple rows

Comment: @NickW, I have tried inserting one by one, using insert and it works, so probably you are right. But then, if it is required to use COPY INTO, how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: `COPY` is an all or nothing action, you cannot step though it.  You will need to come up with another way of doing this.